# Textview in Dialog Fragment is not getting visible when we try to show the textview from its parent class

Tags: android, android-view, textview, android-dialogfragment

I have a class called "text". and then I have Dialog Fragment named "dialog" under this "text" class.

I am trying to make visible the text from the showText() which is located in the "text" class.

But it's getting visible. it's getting visible only from the dialog fragment.

Could anyone please help find out the issue.

```
        private class text extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            dialog dialogobj = new dialog();
            dialogobj.show(mActivity.getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
            dialogobj.showText();
         }

            public class dialog extends DialogFragment {
                private TextView mText1;
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setRetainInstance(true);
                    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog);
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_layout, container, false);

                    mText1 = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.left_img_view);
                }

                private void showText() {
                    mText1.setVisibility(View.Visible);
                } 
            }
        }
```

Comment: `public void dialog extend DialogFragment ` ?? Whats this ? `Which language is this ?

Comment: Please explain proper with exact code base

Comment: @ADM Thanks... I have changed now.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the variable mText1 as textview, but when call the findViewById method you are casting with Imageview. Check if it is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I advise using a capital letter as the first letter of your classes.

I think you should try to call your dialog initialization in the onCreate method of the Activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        dialog.showText();
    }
```